# Removing specific set of characters in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, and want to use another list of strings and remove any instance of the combination of bad list in my list. Such as the output of the below would be foo, bar, foobar, foofoo... Currently I have tried a few things for example below

```
mylist = ['foo!', 'bar\\n', 'foobar!!??!!', 'foofoo::!*']
remove_list = ['\\n', '!', '*', '?', ':']

for remove in remove_list: 
    for strings in mylist:
        strings = strings.replace(bad, ' ')
```

The above code doesnt work, I did at one point set it to a new variable and append that afterwords but that wasnt working well becuase if their was two issues in a string it would be appended twice.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave a list of what you expected the code to do. You're only replacing things you're iterating over, but I don't see any result in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the temporary variable, not the original list.  Instead, assign the result back into `mylist`

```
for bad in remove_list: 
    for pos, string in enumerate(mylist):
        mylist[pos] = string.replace(bad, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mylist = ['foo!', 'bar\\n', 'foobar!!??!!', 'foofoo::!*']
bads = ['\\n', '!', '*', '?', ':']
result = []
for s in mylist:
  # s is a temporary copy
  for bad in bads:
    s = s.replace(bad, '') # for all bad remove it
  result.append(s)
print(result)
```

Could be implemented more concise, but this way it's more understandable.

Comment: We think alike!

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time interpreting the question, but I see you have the result desired at the top of your question.

```
mylist = ['foo!', 'bar\\n', 'foobar!!??!!', 'foofoo::!*']
remove_list = ['\\n', '!', '*', '?', ':']

output = output[]
for strings in mylist:
    for remove in remove_list: 
        strings = strings.replace(remove, '')
    output.append(strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can use is a comprehension list and remove the characters you want.  After that, you delete duplicates.

```
list_good = [word.replace(bad, '') for word in mylist for bad in remove_list]
list_good = list(set(list_good))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
for list1 in mylist:
    t = regex.sub('', list1)
    print(t)
```

If you just want to get rid of non-chars do this. It works a lot better than comparing two separate array lists.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have regex do the work for you? No nested loops this way *(just make sure to escape correctly)*:

```
import re

mylist = ['foo!', 'bar\\n', 'foobar!!??!!', 'foofoo::!*']
remove_list = [r'\\n', '\!', '\*', '\?', ':']
removals = re.compile('|'.join(remove_list))

print([removals.sub('', s) for s in mylist])
```

---

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foofoo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list = ["foo!", "bar\\n", "foobar!!??!!", "foofoo::*!"]
to_remove = ["!", "\\n", "?", ":", "*"]

for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    for char in to_remove:
        if char in item:
            item = item.replace(char, "")
        my_list[index] = item
print(my_list) # outputs [“foo”,”bar”,”foobar”,”foofoo”]
```